# Client-Server between Android and PC over WIFI

Tags: java, android, client-server, serversocket

I am testing the communication between the Android and my Laptop.

I have a Lan connection and I shared the Internet through the laptops WiFi

**Now I have created a Server on laptop with the code**

```
            public void run()
    {
        try {                       
            server_soc = new ServerSocket(1234);


            display.append("Server Started on port : " + server_soc);
            display.append("\nWaiting for client to connect ");

            while(true){
                cli=server_soc.accept();

                display.append("\nClient connected ");

                Accept_Client accept_client=new Accept_Client(cli);
                accept_client.start();
            }
```

the server starts successfully.
[image: Server]

I have to connect an android client (android 4.0.4) to this server. I am not able to connect to this Server. What should be the IP used to connect to this server ?

Client (android) code :

```
        Connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        try {

            Server = new Socket("10.0.2.2",1234);
            Server_Msg.setText("connected to Server ");         


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
});
```

I tried all the IPs :192.168.137.1, 123.238.143.130
What should be the IP ?

I have even set up port forwarding in my wireless router. Do I need to do anything in firewall ? Please suggest !

Comment: did you get this resolved? were either of the answers correct? pls mark them if so. I am interested in doing the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Server-client system using real android device you just have to make sure that the port you are listening to is added in firewall.

The server will listen to that port and all the connections coming on that port from any IP will be connected.

Answer (score 0):

To connect from the emulator to a WiFi server on `localhost`, use the `IP 10.0.2.2`
To connect from an Android device to a server you're running on your own network, use the IP of the Wifi server.

Make sure the Internet permissions are set in the Android Manifest file:
As a child node to the  node, insert:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```